# Equal Chess Control

Tags: chess, optimization, construction

Is it possible to setup a chess board where every square on the board is only controlled once. Occupying a square does not mean controlling it.

If it is possible, with how little pieces?

**Piece Cost:**

- Pawn: 1
- Bishop: 3
- Knight: 3
- Rook: 5
- Queen: 9

You are not allowed to use the king.

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/a-flood-of-chess-puzzles?cb=1

Comment: "Once and only once", or "at least once"?

Comment: Once and only once, "only controlled once".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it very hard to only control each square once. Any attempt at limiting the physical number of pieces was turning into an issue. I suspect this can be beaten, but I can manage the whole board in 32 pawns. At least they're only 1 point each.

32.

[image: 32 Points]

Comment: :) This time it wasnt explicit that they have to be of the same colour, so yeah this is good and I dont think this can be beaten, at least not easily

Comment: @skv would it have mattered if they were all white? Each square would still only be controlled once.

Comment: @Joel Great work! I wonder if it's possible without it all being 32 pawns... Can 32 be beaten?

Comment: @skv wait I see it now, so yea both colours are allowed.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/equal-chess-control-with-one-color

Comment: I managed 34 with 4 rooks and 14 pawns, but this turns out to be a really hard puzzle.