# Equal Chess Control With One Color

Tags: chess

Using only the one colour set; Is it possible to setup a chess board where every square on the board is only controlled once. Occupying a square does not mean controlling it.

If it is possible, with how little pieces?

**Piece Cost:**

- Pawn: 1
- Bishop: 3
- Knight: 3
- Rook: 5
- Queen: 9

**You are not allowed to use the king.**

**All pawns must face the same direction**

Comment: Is this really not close enough to your other question? Just adding "pawns facing the sanme way" doesn't add **that** much to the question, does it? What's next, same thing but limited to one full set of pieces?

Comment: @Joe This question actually limits the possible answers a lot. Using only one colour, and pawns in only one direction, makes it quite a bit more challenging. Look at the answer in my previous question, it would not work here.

Comment: I can manage 34 points with 2 colors and one full set of pieces. I haven't figured out anything using a single color full set of pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can manage 34. I haven't gotten better than that. 4 rooks, 14 pawns.

34.

[image: 34 Points]

Comment: You are a genius

Comment: Aren't you only allowed one color set? How would this work with two rooks and eight pawns? I like this answer it just got me thinking...

Comment: Also I think you could stagger the rooks and remove the first 2 pawns from the front of the board.

Comment: Not just one color set. I haven't come close with that.

Comment: Can't stagger the rooks because then they both control the same square.

Comment: Even when it looks like this? http://i.imgur.com/bn7QOy6.png **EDIT**: nevermind, I see the rule about overlapping the rooks.

Comment: I'm a bit curious... how do you personally solve puzzles like this? Does it involve a lot of trial and error? How structured would you say your method is?

Comment: My methods are completely unstructured, so mostly trial and error. I generally start with pieces I think will work well for the puzzle, then adjust from there. I also make sure to try a few completely unrelated solutions (I've tried a bishop solution here with some success but always leaving a few hard-to-control squares). I use a real board and winboard (but not both at once). I prefer a real board, but only have 1 set of pieces, which is fine for most puzzles. With most of the puzzles, it's a matter of recognizing the important part when you find it (in this case, the double rooks).

Comment: Any idea what the maximum total piece value is, subject to the conditions?  It's suprisingly hard to end up with each square controlled exactly once.  Also, do you know of a convenient chessboard editor that would have any assistance for "proofing" a solution?

Comment: No idea. I haven't gotten anything to work other than variations of this (so my max and min are both 34). As for proofing, the only chessboard I've used is winboard, so if I were going to proof something, I'd write a program to take the winboard "paste position to clipboard" data and parse it to determine this puzzle (or others). That is actually a big help because I have just taken a position, pasted it into notepad, modified it and pasted it back. Much easier than setting each piece up manually.

Comment: @JoelRondeau: I wonder what the situation would be if it was required that every square be attacked exactly twice?

Answer (score -2):

Does this count?

> Only one knight because the Knight's tour.

Comment: Here, warspyking is asking for a solution where every square is being attacked. A knight's tour doesn't qualify, since at any given moment only eight (or less) squares are being attacked by the knight.